# Facebook Test account able to tag friend w/old tagging API, using new iOS sdk

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

When testing the publishing/tagging feature of our app I ran into an issue that makes me wonder if our test accounts are actually using v2 of the Facebook API.

I upgraded our app to use the new Facebook iOS SDK to try to publish a photo and tag a friend, but kept using the v1 tagging API. And it worked. I was using one of the Facebook test accounts that we have created (not a "tester account"). This test user is set to use v2.2 of the Facebook API, so we were assuming the tagging feature would not work.

When I use my own personal Facebook account, which is an admin account, tagging a friend does not work. This is expected since the Facebook developer documentation clearly says the admins, devs and testers will default to using v2 of the Facebook API after 2/26/2015.

So now I'm trying to figure out how to know for sure if an account is using v2 of the Facebook API. The override setting on the test user is very clear, and it is set to v2.2.

Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: What do you mean by “the v1 tagging API”?

Comment: Facebook Graph API 1.x. I'm just upgrading to v2.2 and haven't implemented the new taggable api yet.